# Is their any drawback calling WCF service inside CacheItemupdateCallback?

Tags: c#, wcf, caching

Is their any drawback having a logic inside CacheItemUpdateCallback specially I'm calling WCF service inside it?

I want my application to lookup in the cache and let the update call back do the job to update my expensive cache item. Is this a good approach?

This is my sample code :

```
public class CacheItemRepository : ICacheItemRepository
{
    private readonly IItemService _service;
    private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
    private static string CacheItemKey = "_itemkey_";

    public CacheItemRepository(IItemService service, ICacheManager cacheManager)
    {
        _service = service;
        _cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    public IList<Item> GetAllItem()
    {
        IList<Item> item = null;

        if (_cacheManager.TryGet(CacheItemKey, out item))
            return item;

        item = _service.GetAllItem();

        // Assumming I have CachePolicy here that expire every 15 secs.
        _cacheManager.Add(CacheItemKey, item, CachePolicy, CacheItemUpdateCallback );

        return item;
    }


    private void CacheItemUpdateCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason removedReason)
    {
        var itemList = value as IList<Item>;

        var items = _service.GetAllItem(); // Assume this return IList<Item>

        // Compare itemlist to items and if the two is not the same 
        // Assuming I have comparer here

        // Remove old cache
        _cacheManager.Remove(CacheItemKey);            

        // And add new one and assumming I have CachePolicy here that expire every 15 secs.            
        _cacheManager.Add(CacheItemKey, item, CachePolicy, CacheItemUpdateCallback ); 
    }
}
```